# Can I create a normal button while using foundation?

Tags: zurb-foundation

This is the code I'm using to create a button:

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

And the button being created is the same as the default button that Foundation creates for you.

Is it possible to reset Foundation's style and make the button looks like a browser default one?